# Overcoming the openssh / sftp jailroot unwritable

Tags: ssh, openssh, sftp, chroot

we have set up openssh / sftp with a jailroot via chroot; it's well established that a client can't write (upload files to) this root; you need to set up a writable subfolder. However, we have hundreds of clients already out there configured to upload to /. In order to avoid manually reconfiguring them all (our only option), I'm wondering if there is any way to execute any code on the SERVER (not the client) to change the clients session to a writable subfolder when they connect? I'm sure I could code an ssh server to do this, but, that's a lot of work, and could expose security issues too if I don't do it right (which I'm certain not to)... Any ideas on this; either how to change the working directory of a connected session from the SERVER, or some other suggestion entirely that works too... (like hey try this great free sftp server that lets you do just this...)

Thanks